# Are products like redguard fit for use as a waterproofing membrane for shower pans or floor applications?

Tags: shower, waterproofing, cost-effective

Given that you pour your own pan - lets not worry about the exact material but obviously it would be porous.  Can you use a "waterproofing paint" to create your pan without any other waterproofing membrane?

This question [Building on top of 3/4'' plywood subfloor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30640/building-on-top-of-3-4-plywood-subfloor) touches on the topic.  I have not personally done this but I am not sure I would be opposed to it.  Given that Kerdi is selling at like 50 times cost to make and it is a long process to install correctly... Do we have the technology now to paint on our waterproofing?  I am talking floor applications here.

Comment: Their site claims it's suitable for waterproofing pools, so imagine it'd work on shower pan: http://www.custombuildingproducts.com/products/surface-preparation/membranes-underlayments/redgard.aspx#prodTechDocs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redguard ([tech sheet](http://www.custombuildingproducts.com/TDS/TDS-104.pdf)) passes the ANSI A118.10 and A118.12, which include waterproofing

Shower pans are a critical assembly and have to be treated as a system.  Both Schluter (sheet membrane [Kerdi](http://www.schluter.com/8_2_kerdi_drain_3963.aspx)) and Laticrete (liquid membrane [Hydroban](http://www.laticrete.com/architects/products/shower_systems/drains/productid/146.aspx)) use a wide flange drain assembly that improves the transition area between membrane and drain.

[image][image]

Comment: would you use it to waterproof a shower?  potentially could save a TON of money if so.

Comment: Not for the floor pan. The interface of the drain to the Redguard is too narrow and the potential for leaking overtime and VERY minimal shifting is too high. The wide flange drains meant for sheet membranes have several inch wide transition areas much more forgiving of shifts (or even minor cracks).  One minor crack at the Redguard/drain area is 'Game Over'.  100% ok for walls above the pan (4 inches above shower floor.

Comment: What do you think about something like kerdi used around the drain and integrated into the paint further out?

Comment: Putting down sheet membrane is more in my comfort zone (which was the final thought for http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30640/building-on-top-of-3-4-plywood-subfloor).  But since Laticrete has a wide flange drain that works with HydroBan, it would work fine with Redguard (but don't count on warranties from either mfgr.)

Comment: I never count on warranties anyway.  I have never gotten a penny back past the cost of materials no matter how bad the product or how big the company.  Every time I install Kerdi I think about the amount of overkill.  I would think there would be an easier way to do these things - double drain system that you could implant in concrete... Something like that.