# How high must a shower pan curb be?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, waterproofing

Releated to: [Building on top of 3/4'' plywood subfloor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30640/building-on-top-of-3-4-plywood-subfloor)

(link for impatient: http://www.mrmoneymustache.com/2012/12/21/how-to-make-a-relatively-sweet-shower-cheap/)

I would like to know how high the shower pan curb should be. I have read somewhere that 2" is the minimum while a lot of examples (Lowes,HD, tile stores) have some about 6".

So, my question: is there a rule? If so how high?

**Bonus points** There must be some sort of calculation I can do for this:

- amount of water coming out of standard shower
- volume of shower pan
- amount of water being drained

yields how long it would take to overflow the shower pan.

Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made a "curbless" shower for a relative last year.

Basically two things that I had to abide by:

#1 - Your slope must be between 1/4 and 1/2 inch per foot.

#2 - Everything must be waterproofed up until 2 inches above drain.

That's it.

Comment: Indeed, this corresponds to construction for wheelchair accessible showers I have recently seen in new construction.

Answer (score 5):

The shower pan curb must be a minimum of 2 inches above the top of the drain.  This is common building code in the U.S.  For example, if you have a 1/4 inch per foot slope, and the curb is 3 feet from the drain, the curb must raise 1 1/4 inch from the shower floor.  Of course, this is for the finished shower.  The curb will be higher before you put in the pan.  The 6 inch figure you are finding is for the shower pan liner.  The liner should go up the shower walls at least 6 inches.